# Java (console) columns with more than one data type per column

Tags: java, format

I'll start right off the bat by saying that this was a homework project (that was submitted weeks ago). I got decent marks, but I would like to know if I could have done it better.

We had to output an Employee's name, age, salary and bonus in this format:

```
Name        Age     Salary      Bonus
Xxxxxx      xx      $ xxxxx.xx  $ xxxx.xx
```

We aren't allowed to use loops and only have to output one employee.

Now this is how I did the output:

```
String employeeSalary = String.format("%.2f", myEmployee.getSalary());
String employeeBonus = String.format("%.2f", myEmployee.calculateBonus());

System.out.printf("\f%-10s %-10s %-12s %-10s\n", "Name", "Age", "Salary", "Bonus");
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-12s %-10s", myEmployee.getName(), myEmployee.getAge(), "$ " + employeeSalary, "$ " + employeeBonus);
```

Thank you,

Mike :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows you are already aware of `format` method in `String` class. So you could have used it to format entire output instead of using both `format` and `printf` methods.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %-10s $ %-12.2f $ %-10.2f", 
                    myEmployee.getName(), myEmployee.getAge(), 
                    myEmployee.getSalary(), myEmployee.calculateBonus()));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I wasn't aware you could put strings directly into the "formatting" part of the format() method.  :D